# python list comprehension for loop in for loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

What the beat way to convert:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4)] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I tried

```
[i for i in row for row in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]]
```

but it's not work.

Comment: Yes, it's a dumplicate question in some kind. I just can't find it(I don't know how to expression this question). Thanks for your mention.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this also with chain from itertools

```
from itertools import chain
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
print(list(chain.from_iterable(a)))

>>>>[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is the best way to do this

```
>>> L = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>> [j for i in L for j in i]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note that the "outer loop" variable needs to come first

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [i for row in [(1, 2), (3, 4)] for i in row]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

---

```
[i for row in [(1, 2), (3, 4)] for i in row]
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  # you need define 'row' before define 'i'
```